# Creating file geodatabase and using it as variable to create file path?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

It's been a while since I've done arcpy scripting so it feels kind of new again. I'm working a script that is asking for these 5 parameters:

```
workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)    
RouteLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)   
StateLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
StateTaxDistricts = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
NewGDB = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace, NewGDB)
```

What I want to do is to use the new GDB as a variable and create a location for outputs. I want to do something like this:

```
newLocation = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace, NewGeodatabase)  
clipLayer = arcpy.Clip_analysis(RouteLayer, StateLayer, newLocation + name + "Clip")
```

I've got a few other tools that are using the same format for the output. I have a clip, intersect, split line at point, and spatial join.

When I run my tool, it crashes and calls out this line: `newLocation = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace, NewGeodatabase)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the full traceback/error.  Note that most tools return an `arcpy.Result()` object rather than the output path directly-- most of the time this can be used as the input into subsequent tools, but not always.  And to build paths in Python, look into using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) rather than manually concatenating strings

Comment: Try using arcpy.AddMessage after each GetParameterAstext to print what your tool dialog is passing to your script, and show us the output of those messages.

Answer (score 2):

First, your error may (but not sure as you didn't include the full error text) be caused by passing a [`Result` object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/result.htm) to `arcpy.Clip_analysis`.  The `arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management` tool returns a `Result` object, not a string.

You can do a couple of things:

```
import os

result = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace, NewGeodatabase)  

newLocation = result.GetOutput(0)
#OR
newLocation = os.path.join(workspace, NewGeodatabase)
```